# nextjs server stops a few seconds after running "npm run dev"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created a new project. I use the nextjs tutorial to create next js with react and tried to run with "npm run dev".
The app started

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
```

but a few seconds later stops with no errors.
node version v19.7.0
next version 13.2.4

tried also uninstall and install node.
downgrade also the 'nextjs' version.

added -verbose but everything looks ok

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade the node version to 18?

Comment: No. downgrade node can be a problem for me. maybe for last result but for now i want to try other solutions (if there are). Thanks.

Comment: @S.T Maybe you can try using https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm then you don't need to downgrade but you can easily switch between different Node versions.

Comment: i used nvm, changed node version to 17.3.0 and 18.0.0 and still have the same issue.
Nothing new in the logs.

Comment: Try running the app in debug mode with the command npm run dev --inspect. This will start the app with the Node.js debugger and allow you to step through the code to find the issue.

Comment: still nothing. i tried it on a different mac with node 16.16.0 and it works.
I changed mine to 16.16.0 with nvm and still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was my mac operating system that was old. I had catalina  and i upgrade it to big sur and now it is working.
Thanks all.